# Не отключается скрипт на объекте, юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

Суть проблемы в том, что в игре, есть скрипт, который отключает другой скрипт на другом объекте. Раньше все работало нормально, но, видимо, я что-то дернул, и скрипт не отключается НИКАК. Ни в инспекторе, ни в скрипте, никак. Если его отключить перед началом игры, он включится автоматически. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: это связано с тем, что вы что-то дернули

Comment: ну тут не поспоришь)))

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете в виду отсутствие галочки на скрипте в инспекторе, как у `Transform`, `Rigidbody` или `Mesh Filter`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То скрипт не отключаем, если не содержит `Update`, `FixedUpdate`, `OnGUI` и т.д.
То есть отключать нечего, остальные функции работают даже в отключенном скрипте.

Comment: нет-нет, галочка есть